# WinpCap block internet access

Tags: c++, networking, winpcap

I want to block internet access for the particular website like yahoo or gmail or any other. I researched a lot on google and came up with the library which offer packet sniffing and manipulation. I can read packet and get the destination ip and source ip address of the server and the client computer. as far as my understanding related to the topic is, to block the any url i need to send the FIN packet to the server which indicates to the server that I don't want any more packets. so I need to create a packet with destination ip address and send it to the server (like yahoo etc). can you help me on this, some code snippet or way around, or any other correct approach for this task.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You may consider searching for `filtering proxy`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/main.html

Start with understanding on how to "trace" the packets, read filtered packets, what Raw IP is and then attempt on blocking/modifiying the packets. WinPcap is powerful, but may not be easy to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://netfiltersdk.com/ successfully. Its a commercial project but they have a demo version which you could use for your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you can apply your blocking rules on the Internet traffic which flows through your pipe. The key is to direct all traffic to pass through your pipe and your application which operates on that pipe decides what to pass and what to block.  But here we have Winpcap which is used for sniffing, packet injection, statistics gathering e.t.c just like a spectator watching whats going on. Its not used to block a packet coming from Internet.